# How to get a key with knowing only one value

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-native

I've been going back and forward with this thing for a week now and can't get to a solution with it. Basically I want to remove something from firebase database but the thing is that I don't know what key is. So I added a server timestamp which should be a unique thing and now I would like to find that timestamp in the database and remove that child/node, however u call this, to which that timestamp belongs.

This part creates views with the info from the database and when I would click on that image I would like to remove it from the database.

```
<View style={styles.itemsList}>
                    {this.props.items.map((item, index) => {
                        if (item.ttype == 0) {
                            return (
                                <View key={index} style={styles.viewHolderNegative}>
                                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.removeSelected(item.timestamp)}>
                                        <Image source={require('./assets/remove24.png')}></Image>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                    <Text style={styles.textTransaction}>{item.name}</Text>
                                    <Text style={[styles.textTransaction, { fontSize: 20 }]}>{item.date}</Text>
                                </View>
                            );
                        } else if (item.ttype == 1) {
                            return (
                                <View key={index} style={styles.viewHolderPositive}>
                                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.removeSelected(item.timestamp)}>
                                        <Image source={require('./assets/remove24.png')}></Image>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                    <Text style={styles.textTransaction}>{item.name}</Text>
                                    <Text style={[styles.textTransaction, { fontSize: 20 }]}>{item.date}</Text>
                                </View>
                            );
                        }
                    })}
                </View>
```

Comment: can you add code of `this.removeSelected` method?

Comment: Don't have anything in it since I didn't come to any solution. Just tried a few console logs to see where would I come to but didn't get to anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are aware of firebase methods, if not then check firebase docs for react-native,

you can achieve removing an item by `remove()` method but you will have to acknowledge which item to remove.

for that, you will have to give key in `child(key)` method.

see this,

```
firebase.database().ref('ITEMS').child('KEY').remove();
```

`ITEMS` is the collection name and `KEY` is your timestamp.

Comment: It doesn't work. Don't know if we are on the same line here but timestamp is not the key. I'm using `push` to insert data into the database so the key is a randomly generated string and that timestamp is the one which is included under that randomly generated key or at the end of all of that I understand those things wrong

Comment: **I want to remove something from firebase database but the thing is that I don't know what key is. So I added a server timestamp** that's why I assumed that key is your timestamp, anyways use the key that you want to delete and if you have used an auto-generated key then you'll have to change the logic of adding custom key while adding new data. you can use `set()` or `update()` method to assign your own key

Comment: Yea I did write the question a bit weird. I'm already trying with `set()` and want to use a timestamp as a key but I can't for some odd reason

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Yea I did. The timestamp version that I was using was actually executed on the server once it was added so outside of that it just returns a useless object so then I used `Date.now()` and that worked and also added the same value under the child so I can search by that value and then the key is the same so I can easily remove it